# SQL: How can I select a value with associated value from my table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a `SQL SELECT` that displays the player's username and the name of the team associated with the player. This is my code but it don't works like expected:

```
SELECT Player.userName AS Player, 
     Teams.TeamName AS [Team Name]
FROM Players, Teams
    INNER JOIN Players
        ON Team.ID = Player.userName
```

This is the Team's table 
[image]

This is the player's table I just included the names only. 
[image]

[This is the full Player's Table with the contents of what is inside the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J77sc.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow, We need to see the data in the players table, at least the first few rows.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between your `teams` and `players` tables. How do you, as a human, know which player belongs to which team? Is there a `team id` column in that `players` table you aren't showing us?

Comment: Thanks! I added a new image of the Player's table

Comment: `FROM Players
    INNER JOIN Teams
        ON Team.ID = Players.[teamName_]`

Answer (score 3):

1. Your syntax is a bit off in your FROM clause. The best rule of thumb here is to *NEVER* use a comma in your `FROM` clause (the only exception is if you want to join *EVERY* row from one table to *EVERY* row of another creating a cartesian product of the two tables, but we rarely do that).
2. When you specify the relationship of the two tables in the `ON` clause of your `JOIN` you need to put the column(s) from each table that they have in common. A `Team.ID` will *NEVER* match to a `Players.userName`, so that is not the proper join condition.

Assuming you have a `TeamID` column in your players table so you know which `Team` each `Player` is on, you will have SQL that will look like:

```
SELECT Players.userName AS Player, 
     Teams.TeamName AS [Team Name]
FROM Teams
    INNER JOIN Players
        ON Team.ID = Players.[TeamName_]
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation! I tried inputting this sql code into my database to see what I got and it came up an error, Syntax error in Join operation

Comment: Right, because you probably don't have a column named `TeamID`. I have no idea what your `player` table looks like except for the partial screenshot you shared above, so you'll have to edit that to fit your schema.

Comment: I added a new image of the Player's table

Comment: Great. I've updated the answer. You want to join `ON` your `Team.ID` to your `Player.[TeamName_]` field. That tells Access the relationship between those two tables.

Comment: corrected `player` to `players` on select and join criteria.  (error propagated from OP) though maybe the table name is player.... and not players and it was wrong....

Comment: @xQbert Nice catch. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! It still says there is an syntax error In the JOIN operation

Comment: There's not much I can do for you there. The Syntax is correct, as far as I can tell. Double check that the column and table names match your tables and columns. Does it say anything besides "Syntax Error" or is it really just that generic?